# How should I go about implementing a points-to analysis in Maude?

Tags: data-structures, logic-programming

I'm going to implement a [points-to analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_analysis) algorithm. I'd like to implement this analysis mainly based on [the algorithm by Whaley and Lam](http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/996841.996859). Whaley and Lam use a [BDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_Decision_Diagrams) based implementation of [Datalog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datalog) to represent and compute the points-to analysis relations.

The following lists some of the relations that are used in a typical points-to analysis. Note that `D(w, z) :− A(w, x),B(x, y), C(y, z)` means `D(w, z)` is true if `A(w, x)`, `B(x, y)`, and `C(y, z)` are all true. BDD is the data structure used to represent these relations.

**Relations**

```
input vP0 (variable : V, heap : H)
input store (base : V, field : F, source : V)
input load (base : V, field : F, dest : V)
input assign (dest : V, source : V)
output vP (variable : V, heap : H)
output hP (base : H, field : F, target : H)
```

**Rules**

```
vP(v, h) :− vP0(v, h)
vP(v1, h) :− assign(v1, v2), vP(v2, h)
hP(h1, f,h2) :− store(v1, f, v2), vP(v1, h1), vP(v2, h2)
vP(v2, h2) :− load(v1, f, v2), vP(v1, h1), hP(h1, f, h2)
```

I need to understand if [Maude](http://maude.cs.uiuc.edu/) is a good environment for implementing points-to analysis. I noticed that Maude uses a BDD library called [BuDDy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/buddy/). But, it looks like that [Maude uses BDDs for a different purpose, i.e. unification](http://maude.cs.uiuc.edu/talks/eker-unification.pdf). So, I thought I might be able to use Maude instead of a Datalog engine to compute the relations of my points-to analysis. I assume Maude propagates independent information concurrently. And this concurrency could potentially make my points-to analysis faster than sequential processing of rules. But, I don't know the best way to represent my relations in Maude. Should I implement BDD in Maude myself, or Maude's internal unification based on BDD has the same effect?